# Saving an answer for offline viewing

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

I want to save a lengthy answer to a question, to read on the bus tomorrow morning - to remain productive, rather than stare at the road.

I'm too poor to afford mobile internet; is there a way I can nicely view this offline, say, by converting it to an image or pdf?

I could take 10 screen-shots of the answer, is this the best way?
I use windows phone, which I don't think has an option to manually cache a page for later viewing.

Answer (score 4):

Most browsers offer a Print option for webpages, and it's trivial to get a PDF printer (download from Adobe, or installed by default on most current operating systems).

Print the page, drop the PDF in onedrive, pull to phone, cry a little over the way Microsoft has utterly trashed the windows phone platform, and enjoy.